# How to plot data on map without coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot dataframe like:

```
code    name             description    estimate
0       Australia         Vegetables     854658
0       Australia         Fruit          667541
1       New South Wales   Vegetables     45751
1       New South Wakes   Fruit          77852
2       Victoria          Vegetables     66211
2       Victoria          Fruit          66211
. 
.
.
```

For each region in Australia there are multiple rows with different description. What packages may I use to plot a map with estimate without coordinates?
I try `ggplot` and `ozmaps` with `sf` which mentioned in ggplot2 tutorial, and I filter the dataframe for only fruit, but there is error message :
`stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry`
the code I tried :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(oz_states,mapping=aes())+
  geom_sf(df,mapping=aes()) +
  coord_sf()
```

The methods I found are all required langitude and latitude to plot the data map, I tried `ggmaps` or `geom_ploygon` but didn't figure out the correct way to do so.  Is there a possible way to plot map with only region labels?
this is what I plot by tableau, and this is expected plot by using r as well:
[image: this is what I plot by tableau]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you not pull the lat/long coordinates from the internet, save it as a .csv and then join to your current dataframe on name? Or do you have to do it explicitly without the internet?

Comment: @HanselPalencia it is fine to pull coordinates from the internet, but it is not a good option to me, I'm trying to do without adding external info. Also I'm curious if there is a method or package could be used to plot simply with labels.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially, your first problem is that you're calling the wrong object within the `ozmaps` package. it's `ozmap_states`, meanwhile you called yours `oz_states`

I came up with this solution that I think takes what you want and elevates it.

```
df <- data.frame(code = rep(c(0,1,2), 2), name = rep(c("Australia", "New South Wales", "Victoria"), 2), description = rep(c("Vegetables", "Fruit"), 3), count =
             c(854658, 45751, 66211, 667541, 77852, 66211))

library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ozmaps)
library(leaflet)
library(tmap)

states_full <- right_join(df, ozmap_states, by = c("name" = "NAME"))

data <- states_full %>% 
  filter(description == "Fruit") %>% 
  select(name, geometry, count)

ozmap1 = tm_shape(ozmap_states) +tm_polygons()


tmap_mode("view")

ozmap1 + tm_shape(st_as_sf(data)) + tm_fill(col = "count")
```

Basically, instead of using the sample dataframe that I created from your data, you would just use your data in the right join. You can also choose whether you want fruits or vegetables in your filter function.

The tmap package is a mapping package that can make interactive leaflet like maps.

You can look at some tutorials here: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html

End solution looks something like this.

[image]

Note: This solution uses lng/lat, but it pulls it directly from the shape file for oz state maps in the ozmaps package, therefore fulfilling the need of the question.

When you add in more data, more of Australia will be colored in depending on their count.